# How can i calculate a string of operator and operands

Tags: java

### It is giving error when operator is encountered in between.I know operator cannot be into        converted int or other format.I am using operator for calculation by reading byte codes and passing   it to enum defined.But as my string having operators so i am having prob in handling these.Please help me on this.

```
My Inputs is 1 + 2
Expected Output-- 1 +  2=3
```

Error in line ---- b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

```
 ------Error in during exceution-----
   Hello World
Enter the series
1 + 2
1 + 2

no of tokens:3
yo
1
go
1
available

byte info:10
.......
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:484)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Abc.main(Abc.java:42) 





I am not able to rectify it. Below is my code


import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Abc{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
System.out.println("Hello World");
System.out.println("Enter the series");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s=br.readLine();
int a=0;
int b=0;
System.out.println(s);
while ((br.readLine()) != null) 
{
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s);

while (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
int i=0;
i=st.countTokens();
System.out.println("no of tokens:"+i);
String token = st.nextToken();
System.out.println("yo");
System.out.println(token);
System.out.println("go");



a=Integer.parseInt(token);
System.out.println(a);


 if (st.hasMoreTokens()) // before consuming another token, make sure 
         {
        System.out.println("available");
        byte b1=(byte)br.read();
        System.out.println("byte info:"+b1);
                         // there's one available
                         if (st.hasMoreTokens()){
              System.out.println(".......");
        b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());  
         System.out.println("///////");

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println("reached");
System.out.println(b);
}
if (b1==43)
{
System.out.println("go");
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.ADDITION, a, b));
}
else if (b1==45)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.SUBTRACTION, a, b));
}
else if (b1==42)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.MULTIPLY, a, b));
}
else if (b1==47)
{
int foo = Integer.parseInt(calculate(operator.DIVIDE, a, b));
}

}
}
}
}

public enum operator
{
    ADDITION("+") {
        public int apply(int  x1, int x2) {
            return x1 + x2;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION("-") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 - x2;
        }
    },
 MULTIPLY("*") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 * x2;
        }
    },
     DIVIDE("/") {
         public int apply(int x1, int x2) {
            return x1 / x2;
        }
    };







 // You'd include other operators too...
private final String text;

    private operator(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    // Yes, enums *can* have abstract methods. This code compiles...
    public abstract int apply(int x1, int x2);

    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}

public static String calculate(operator op, int x1, int x2)
{
    return String.valueOf(op.apply(x1, x2));
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide your input.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not clear what the input and output should be.

Comment: my inputs are 1*2+3 
it is giving output as 

no of tokens:1
1*2+3

10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1+2"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at Abc.main(Abc.java:30)
it is calulating no of tokens as 1 which is wrong it should be 5.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is problematic :

```
   while (st.hasMoreTokens()) // this guarantees only that at least one more 
                              // token exists
   {
       int i=st.countTokens();
       System.out.println("no of tokens:"+i);

       System.out.println(st.nextToken()); // here you consume the only token 
                                           // guaranteed to exist without saving it
       byte b1=(byte)br.read();
       System.out.println(b1);
       int a=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // here you try to get two more
       int b=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // tokens even though there may be 
                                               // none
       System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(b);
    ...
```

You should only consume one token in each iteration of this loop (unless you make another call to `st.hasMoreTokens()` which returns true):

```
   while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
   {
       int i=st.countTokens();
       System.out.println("no of tokens:"+i);

       String token = st.nextToken();
       System.out.println(token);                                         
       byte b1=(byte)br.read();
       System.out.println(b1);
       int a=Integer.parseInt(token);
       int b=0;
       if (st.hasMoreTokens()) // before consuming another token, make sure 
                               // there's one available
           b = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());                    
       System.out.println(a);
       System.out.println(b);
    ...
```

Comment: first thanks for help.. i used this if (st.hasMoreTokens()) but prob is the same ..System.out.println("no of tokens:"+i) giving the wrong output and not going down to code below and giving again the same error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1+2"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at Abc.main(Abc.java:30)

Comment: @MohitDarmwal It's not the same problem. You got a different exception now - "NumberFormatException". This means you are trying to parse a String that contains non numeric characters as an integer.

Comment: yep .. your right its okk now..but now i dont know how to handle  Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) when operators(+,-,*,/) are coming through the string .it is giving error like................. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `br.readline()` and each read a separate line.

Try using `while(s != null)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Always use hasMoreTokens() method before nextToken(). You check for tokens and then you call nextToken() three times without even know if three tokens are available.